# Stripe Error on validating coupon code "Class 'Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException' not found"

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Having a problem while validating Stripe coupon via ajax method. I'm getting "Class 'Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException' not found" error message.

Using Laravel 5.8 and Cashier. All cashier methods seem to be working fine.

My controller code:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Stripe\Coupon;

class HelperController extends Controller {

    public function ajaxCheck(Request $request)
    {

        if($request->has('coupon')){
            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
            try {
                Coupon::retrieve(strtoupper($request->input('coupon')));
            } catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
                return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()], 400);
            }
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Coupon is valid!'], 200);

        }
    }

}
```

Using sample code from https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-cashier-handle-invalidrequest-before-user-creation?page=1

Comment: Exception class names changed in [v7](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/releases/tag/v7.0.0), specifically in [this PR](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/pull/709). You probably want to check which version of stripe-php you're using (whether directly or through Cashier).

Comment: @taintedzodiac My stripe-php is v7.3.0 which I believe includes the PR you mentioned. Now that I know the reason for the missing Exception class, how do I troubleshoot from here?

I also tried ```catch (\Exception $e)``` but getting the same error message.

Comment: I'm not seeing that error when trying out your code with various tests (such as including an empty string for the Coupon ID). Is it possible you're throwing that error somewhere else in your code? Is there a deeper stack trace message you can share that shows where the error is being thrown in your code or from Cashier?

Comment: @taintedzodiac You were right about the version of stripe-php. v7.3.0 did not include modernized exceptions.